# JQuery Quicksearch in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, quick-search

I have a page with a large table that uses jquery quicksearch to quickly search the table.  This function as written works fine in Chrome, FF, and IE8 but in IE9 it fails.  In fact it seems to fail in such a way that the remaining portion of the $(document).ready() doesn't complete.  Any ideas on what I can change in order to get this working in IE9?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#search_box").quicksearch("table#invTable tbody tr", {
                noResults: '#noresults',
                stripeRows: ['odd', 'even'],
                loader: 'span.loading',
                onAfter: function() {
                    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML=($('tr:visible').length-1);
                    }                   
                });
```

EDIT: It looks like this error in the IE9 console is the problem:

> SEC7112: Script from
>   https://raw.github.com/riklomas/quicksearch/dev/jquery.quicksearch.js
>   was blocked due to mime type mismatch

Now I just have to figure out how to fix it!

EDIT2:  File is hosted locally works.  To the commenter who suggested this - add it as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Works in IE8, FF and Chrome but not in IE9? I don't believe it

Comment: ProTip - GH hosted files are served as RAW (plain/text), which is why the MIME does not match up - host the code yourself, or use a CDN. problem solved.

Comment: Esailija - Believe.  They changed something in the way IE9 handles MIME types.  Apparently this even affected twitter APIs when IE9 was first released.

Comment: IE9+ evaluates the mime-type for style-sheets and scripts. This is for security reasons. You can find more online at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/26/mime-handling-changes-in-internet-explorer.aspx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Github-hosted version of this JavaScript file comes down with the `text/plain` mime-type. If you were to host the file locally you wouldn't have this problem, as the content-type would be `text/javascript`. The same rule applies for CSS as well.

Further reading: [MIME-Handling Changes in Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/26/mime-handling-changes-in-internet-explorer.aspx)

[image]